# Python - How to check if the name from file is used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have small scraping script. I have file with 2000 names and I use these names to search for Video IDs in YouTube. Because of the amount it takes pretty long time to get all the IDs so I can't do that in one time. What I want is to find where I ended my last scrape and then start from that position. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking about adding the used name to the list and then just check if it's in the list, if no - start scraping but maybe there's a better way to do this? (I hope yes).

Part that takes name from file and scraped IDs. What I want is when I quit scraping, next time when I start it, it would run not from beginning but from point where it ended last time:

```
index = 0
for name in itertools.islice(f, index, None):
    parameters = {'key': api_key, 'q': name}
    request_url = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&type=video&fields=items%2Fid', params = parameters)
    videoid = json.loads(request_url.text)
    if 'error' in videoid:
        pass
    else:
        index += 1
        id_file.write(videoid['items'][0]['id']['videoId'] + '\n')
        print videoid['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just remember the index number of the last scraped entry. Every time you finish scraping one entry, increment a counter, then assuming the entries in your text file don't change order, just pick up again at that number?

Comment: I'm running a loop to get names from file. How can I get back to wanted line in a loop? I know how can I get index but don't know about getting back. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user1628593: To skip the first n lines in the file, just do `for line in itertools.islice(f, n, None):` instead of `for line in f:`.

Comment: wow, i really need to keep itertools in mind, much more nicer then what I'd have done to skip lines in a file.

Comment: It seems that it's not adding scraped IDs that are already in file but it still goes from beginning in names file. I'll edit first post with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here is probably mitim's answer. Just keep a file that you rewrite with the last-processed index after each line. For example:

```
savepath = os.path.expanduser('~/.myprogram.lines') 
skiplines = 0
try:
    with open(savepath) as f:
        skiplines = int(f.read())
except:
    pass
with open('names.txt') as f:
    for linenumber, line in itertools.islice(enumerate(f), skiplines, None):
        do_stuff(line)
        with open(savepath, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(linenumber))
```

However, there are other ways you could do this that might make more sense for your use case.

For example, you could rewrite the "names" file after each name is processed to remove the first line. Or, maybe better, preprocess the list into an `anydbm` (or even `sqlite3`) database, so you can more easily remove (or mark) names once they're done.

Or, if you might run against different files, and need to keep a progress for each one, you could store a separate `.lines` file for each one (probably in a `~/.myprogram` directory, rather than flooding the top-level home directory), or use an `anydbm` mapping pathnames to lines done.